# Run multiple python scripts with arguments in real time

Tags: python, bash, scripting, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to gather data in realtime. My script saves the data on a timely basis. It requires one input (through using argparse) and uses a virtual environment.

I've tried:

```
for input in inputs:
    python_file = 'PYTHON_IN_CONDA_ENV_DIR DIR/file.py -I "' + input + '"'
    os.system("gnome-terminal --tab -e 'bash -c \"" + python_file + "; exec bash\"'")
```

Nothing shows. An alternative might be multiprocessing, Linux screen, a direct bash script.
I've also tried:

```
#!/bin/bash
for input in $(cat inputs.txt); 
do
    gnome-terminal --tab -e file.py --input=input
done
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Crontab looks like it might be great for this. Scripts needs to run indefinitely.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. Which is the question?

Comment: I'm trying to run a script with a different input arguments multiple times simultaneously.

Essentially, I'm scraping data which needs to be done as quickly as possible. So rather than run file.py --arg a then open a new terminal tab and type in the same things (for up to 200 different processes), I want to write a script that will do this for loop for me.
I want to automate:
source activate environment; python file.py a
source activate environment; python file.py b
etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue with GUI automation: See [MultiPy](https://github.com/JeffreyWardman/MultiPy) on my GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment, it looks like you are looking for something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

source activate environment
for input in $(cat inputs.txt)
do
    python file.py --input="$input" &
done
```

Comment: Yes but 'source' won't work so I replaced it with the complete path of the environment's python: /home/.../env/.../python. Also, I want to run each iteration of the loop at the same time (i.e. 5 different terminals with the input argument being different for each one).

Comment: Man, in every comment yo write you are changing the requirements and the question. Please, write a proper, clear question with the problem you are facing and we will be able to help. Otherwise, we are losing time guessing what you need and writing improper solutions.

Comment: BTW, the loop is starting the iterations one after the other in a rapid succession. Start all of them at exactly the same time is impossible: there will be always a few microseconds of difference. And the `source` command is the one you said in the comment. If that don't work and you have a working one... tell us!

Comment: I haven't changed the question or requirements. I need to run multiple versions of the same script at the same time. Start time doesn't matter. They can start separately. They all run indefinitely as they are for collecting data in real time.

Comment: You said they have to run simultneously, but now you say that start time does not matter. You talk about something running infinitely but you also talk about running it periodically with cron. You said to start a python script but then you changed to start different terminals. Every option have different implementations.

Comment: Thank you for your help Poshi. I ended up using a GUI automation method.